# Number of parameters passed in a Ant command line

Tags: ant

I would know if it's possible using an Ant task to know the number of parameters passed to an Ant target ? For example, with the following command :

```
ant myTarget -Darg1="arg1" -Darg2="arg2"
```

I would like to be able, inside the "myTarget" target, to get that the user passed exactly 2 arguments.

I have built this condition:

```
<condition property="params.set">
    <and>
        <isset property="arg1"/>
        <isset property="arg2"/>
    </and>
</condition>
```

but I would like to add in it a check on the number of passed parameters.

Or perhaps is it possible to get the same information using a groovy task in the "myTarget" target ? I think getting the whole command line would be enough (but how to do this ?) because I can then count the number of " -D" tokens.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your goal for doing this? It's an odd requirement. There might be a better way to accomplish whatever you're trying to do.

Comment: Hi. It's for an internal application. I only would check that the user passed exactly 2 arguments named arg1 and arg2 in the example when invoking the target, otherwise stop the program.

Comment: I get that, but why? There's really no way of doing this other than wrapping it in a shell/bat script.

Comment: We are building a library and this target is made for freezing it when we want by generating a jar file with a special suffix added to the library. Because we use Ant (we have others targets in the build.xml file), we want to do it by adding a "freeze" target. I succeeded but I wanted to add a security: check that the right number of parameters are passed to the Ant command line.

Comment: Since the command line parameters are passed to ant as -D<key>=<value>, you can always check the value of the required parameter.
You just have to make sure its not empty/blank. If the required parameters are passed and are validated, rest can be ignored.

Comment: Thank you, it is indeed a simple solution. I will check that passed parameters are not empty.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would recommend checking for specific properties that the user should not be setting, as opposed to simply counting them and assuming any extras are unwanted. That could make the script rather annoying to deal with if someone is modifying or debugging it later on.

This would be my approach:

```
<fail>
    <condition>
        <or>
            <not>
                <or>
                    <isset property="arg1" />
                    <isset property="arg2" />
                </or>
            </not>
            <isset property="doNotSet1" />
            <isset property="doNotSet2" />
            <isset property="doNotSet3" />
            </or>
    </condition>
</fail>
```

However, if you're dead-set on doing it the way you described, it should technically be possible. Ant stores any properties defined by the initial command in a `propertyset` named "commandline". However, this set includes more than just user properties defined with `-D...`. It will also contain generated properties such as `ant.file` that are set automatically. The number of these properties can vary depending on how your script is configured (for example specifying a default target in the root element), so those will need to be filtered out. Fortunately, these generated properties all begin with `ant.file` or `ant.project`, so they're relatively simple to identify.

```
<fail>
    <condition>
        <or>
            <not>
                <or>
                    <isset property="arg1" />
                    <isset property="arg2" />
                </or>
            </not>
            <resourcecount when="ne" count="2">
                <intersect>
                    <propertyset>
                        <propertyref builtin="commandline" />
                    </propertyset>
                    <propertyset>
                        <propertyref regex="^(?!ant\.(?:file|project))" />
                    </propertyset>
                </intersect>
            </resourcecount>
        </or>
    </condition>
</fail>
```

Comment: I thank you for you complete answer. I will try the tracks you mention.

Answer (score 0):

I finally used:

```
<resourcecount when="ne" count="2">
    <difference>
        <propertyset>
            <propertyref builtin="commandline"/>
        </propertyset>
        <union>
            <propertyset>
                <propertyref prefix="ant.file"/>
            </propertyset>
            <propertyset>
                <propertyref prefix="ant.project"/>
            </propertyset>
        </union>
    </difference>
</resourcecount>
```

with also:

```
<condition>
    <or>
        <equals arg1="${library.name}" arg2=""/>
        <equals arg1="${suffix}" arg2=""/>
    </or>
</condition>
```

and it works well. Thanks again for your answers containing very interesting trails.